# Plastic SCM missing both Merge and Switch Workspace menu options, using with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control, branching-and-merging, plasticscm

**I can't seem to find an explanation for why essential menu operations are missing** in the Plastic SCM Branch Explorer Interface (Unity Dev Ops Version Control).
In Unity's Version Control window, I can switch workspaces, but it seems that merging must take place in the separate Plastic SCM application. I want to merge Color Manager into my main branch, then create a new child branch.

**Has anyone seen this behavior before?**

For context, I'm working by myself and have only tried to copy the project to another computer.

[image: Plastic SCM (Unity Dev Ops Version Control) Branch Explorer Interface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Plastic SCM repositories view, for each repo there are two main options:

1. Download repository: This option will create a local workspace and download the project on disk. After that, all the "Bnrach explorer" view options will be enabled
2. Open repository: You are just opening the "Branch explorer" view to navidate the repo but you do